# Incorrectly display in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have added to the site jquery content slider, but in IE it displays a wry, also displayed a wry header. This screenshot shows all

[image]

Code my webpage:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Bitrix.UI.BXPublicPage, Main"              Title="Социальный образовательный портал" %> 
<script runat="server" id="@__bx_pagekeywords">
    public override void SetPageKeywords(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string> keywords)
    {
        keywords[@"keywords"]=@"";
        keywords[@"description"]=@"";
        keywords[@"ShowLeftColumn"]=@"";
    }
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="bxcontent" runat="server" >
<html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateFirefox" /> 
<title>Документ без названия</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
                    $("#about-button").css({
                opacity: 0.3
            });
            $("#contact-button").css({
                opacity: 0.3
            });
                    $("#page-wrap div.button").click(function(){
                                $clicked = $(this);
                                        if ($clicked.css("opacity") != "1" && $clicked.is(":not(animated)")) {
                                        $clicked.animate({
                        opacity: 1,
                        borderWidth: 5
                    }, 600 );
                    var idToLoad = $clicked.attr("id").split('-');
                    $("#content").find("div:visible").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                        $(this).parent().find("#"+idToLoad[0]).fadeIn();
                    })
                }
                $clicked.siblings(".button").animate({
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }, 600 );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
<div style="width:565px !important;">
  <div id="home-button" class="button" style="margin:0;"><img style="margin:0 !important;" class="button" alt="Социальный образовательный портал" src="button-1.png" /> </div>
<img style="FLOAT: left; margin:0 !important;" src="devide.png" width="2" height="24" /> 
  <div id="about-button" class="button" style="margin:0 !important;"><img style="margin:0 !important;" class="button" alt="Комплектация" src="button-2.png" /> </div>
<img style="FLOAT: left; margin:0 !important;" src="devide.png" width="2" height="24" /> 
  <div id="contact-button" class="button" style="margin:0 !important;"><img style="margin:0 !important;" class="button" alt="План развития системы" src="button-3.png" /> </div>
</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="home">
      <p></p>

      <h1>Социальный образовательный портал</h1>

      <table class="st2">
        <tbody>
          <tr><td style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none" class="left">
              <p>Социальный образовательный портал &ndash; это веб-сервис для обучения через общение всех участников учебного процесса. Как и в любой системе обучения в данном сервисе есть возможность изучения курсов и прохождения тестов. Но главный принцип работы пользователей в сервисе – общение, интерактивное взаимодействие в решении задач и создание личного виртуального пространства.</p>
            </td><td style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none" class="right">
              <p>Участвуя в жизни портала, каждый пользователь сервиса становится частью информационного пространства учебного заведения или организации. Если в привычном понимании портал - это обширная и систематизированная база учебных материалов и документов, то социальный образовательный портал - это актуальные знания каждого из его участников в динамике.</p>
            </td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    <center>
        <table class="st2">
          <tbody>
            <tr><td style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none" class="left">
                <p><img alt="Социальный образовательный портал" src="/project/src001.jpg" width="370" height="236" /></p>
              </td><td style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none" class="right">
                <p><img alt="Социальный образовательный портал" src="/project/src002.jpg" width="370" height="236" /></p>
              </td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </center>
      <table class="st3">
        <tbody>
          <tr><td style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none" class="left">
              <p>В отличие от традиционных систем дистанционного обучения (СДО), данный сервис усиливает направляющую роль преподавателя. Активность обучаемых видна преподавателям, что способствует их профессиональной ориентации, раскрытию творческого потенциала и вовлечению в общественную жизнь. </p>
            </td><td style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none" class="middle">
              <p>Обучаемые также могут наблюдать активность друг друга, что делает процесс обучения прозрачным, мотивирует к соперничеству и достижению лучших результатов в учебной и не учебной деятельности.</p>
            </td><td style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none" class="right">
              <p>В СДО под самостоятельной работой обучаемых фактически подразумевается его изоляция от друзей и от более качественных и актуальных учебных материалов, а Социальный образовательный портал предлагает коллективную работу по выработке и накоплению знаний, где самостоятельность означает лидерство. </p>
            </td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center"><img style="MARGIN-TOP: 20px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 20px" alt="Социальный образовательный портал" src="/project/diag001.jpg" width="810" height="251" /></p>

      <table class="st2">
        <tbody>
          <tr><td style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none" class="left">
              <p>В Социальном образовательном портале используются средства неформального общения, знакомые пользователям по популярным социальным сервисам. Это помогает пользователям более активно взаимодействовать друг с другом: делиться полезной информацией, интенсивно использовать навыки общения, коллективно решать задачи, и выполнять групповые учебные и творческие проекты.</p>

              <p>Используя социальный образовательный портал, Вы получаете управление интеллектуальным капиталом Вашей организации и творческим потенциалом Ваших студентов и работников. В процессе взаимодействия пользователей генерируются уникальные новые решения и информационные ресурсы. Вы можете применять их для последующего цикла обучения и в целях совершенствования бизнес-процессов Вашей организации.</p>
            </td><td style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none" class="right">
              <p><strong>Социальный образовательный портал включает в себя взаимодополняющий функционал продуктов трёх типов:</strong></p>

              <ul>
                <li>система управления сайтом (администрирование, управление правами пользователей, учебные группы, настройка интерфейса, обновление учебного контента, добавление общих компонент: новости, объявления, галереи); </li>

                <li>система дистанционного обучения (курсы и тесты в формате SCORM, статистика обучения, вебинары, календари событий, управление проектным обучением); </li>

                <li>социальная сеть (блоги, группы друзей, фотоальбомы, комментарии, хранение документов, события, закладки и обмен ими). 
                  <br />
                Все пользователи сервиса имеют одинаковый набор инструментов, отличающийся только возможностями, зависящими от роли (студент, преподаватель, куратор и др.) </li>
              </ul>
            </td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <p></p>
    </div>

    <div id="about">
      <h1>Комплектация</h1>

      <p style="MARGIN-TOP: 20px">На текущий момент <strong><em>социальный образовательный портал (СОП)</em></strong> поставляется в двух комплектациях: </p>

      <ol>
        <li><strong>e-Learning standart</strong> </li>

        <li><strong>e-Learning interactive</strong> </li>
      </ol>

      <p>В комплектацию e-Learning interactive помимо базовых функциональных модулей, входящих в конфигурацию e-Learning standart, входит модуль &laquo;Видеочат&raquo;, который поставляеться как в составе модуля e-Learning interactive, так и самостоятельно.</p>

      <p>Используя комплектацию e-Learning standart, Вы получаете простой способ организации замкнутого цикла дистанционного обучения с возможностью получения итоговой статистики.</p>

      <br />
    <center><img alt="Социальный образовательный портал" src="/project/screen_1.jpg" width="628" height="354" /></center>
      <br />

      <p>Функциональные возможности комплектации e-Learning standart:</p>

      <ul>
        <li>система авторизации и разграничения доступа на базе гибкого управления ролями; </li>

        <li>конфигурирование функциональных возможностей с помощью модульного подхода; </li>

        <li>импорт пользователей в в систему на базе популярных форматов; </li>

        <li>загрузка и проигрывание учебных материалов в международном стандарте SCORM; </li>

        <li>управление курсами и учебными группами с использованием календарного плана и расписания; </li>

        <li>личный кабинет пользователя; </li>

        <li>управление видом и содержанием портала с помощью конструктора; </li>

        <li>возможность получения групповой и индивидуальной статистики по результатам обучения; </li>

        <li>возможность публикации новостей на станицах портала с использованием функционального модуля «Новости» и встроенного редактора новостей; </li>

        <li>возможность публикации фотографий на станицах портала с использованием функционального модуля «Фотогалерея» и универсального загрузчика; </li>

        <li>Ваши дискуссии на страницах портала при помощи функционального модуля «Форум». </li>
      </ul>

      <br />

      <p>Мы постарались сделать Ваше on-line общение при обучении максимально комфортным. Для организации вебинаров в социальном образовательном портале (СОП) мы используем богатые возможности приложения FlashChat, которое хорошо зарекомендовало себя при использовании в таких популярных CMS-системах, как Joomla&#33;, Drupal, WordPress и т.д. FlashChat в рамках социального образовательного портала это: </p>

      <br />

      <ul>
        <li>ваши виртуальные комнаты с использованием web-камер; </li>

        <li>общение в чате с использованием привычных инструментов оформления текста и возможностью рисования; </li>

        <li>вставка в чат видео и ссылок на видео с сайта YouTube; </li>

        <li>приватный чат; </li>

        <li>белая доска; </li>

        <li>передача файлов и изображений (опционально); </li>

        <li>возможность пригласить в чат Ваших друзей, отправив им ссылку; </li>

        <li>большое количество разнообразных настроек (настройка расположения видеоокна, смена аватара и т.д.); </li>

        <li>набор предустановленных скинов; </li>

        <li>широкий выбор анимированных смайликов; </li>

        <li>обширные возможности администрирования (опционально): управление пользователями, виртуальными комнатами и многое другое. </li>
      </ul>

      <br />
    <center><img alt="Социальный образовательный портал" src="/project/screen_2.jpg" width="628" height="359" /></center>
      <br />

      <p>Сделать FlashChat неотъемлемой часть СОП нам помогли широкие возможности интеграции, которые мы использовали для того чтобы сделать виртуальное общение неразрывной частью Вашего обучения. Наш вклад в Вашу комфортную работу это:</p>

      <br />

      <ul>
        <li>настройка доступа к видеочату, как отдельному функциональному блоку портала; </li>

        <li>единая система авторизации в рамках СОП; </li>

        <li>данные личного кабинета при общении в чате; </li>

        <li>планирование вебинаров как отдельных мероприятий в календаре; </li>

        <li>управление виртуальными комнатами в рамках прав администратора портала. </li>
      </ul>

      <br />

      <p>По мере выхода новых версий СОП этот вклад будет расширяться. Используйте широкие возможности видеочата при обучении, и оно станет более интерактивным и интересным, а мы поможем Вам в этом, расширяя возможности on-line общения, интегрируя новые функции FlashChat в социальный образовательный портал.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="contact">
      <h1>План развития системы</h1>

      <p style="MARGIN-TOP: 20px">Объявив льготную подписку на социальный образовательный портал (СОП), мы взяли на себя определенные обязательства перед нашими пользователями по выпуску новых версий до конца 2011 года. Этот план мы намерены неукоснительно соблюдать.</p>

      <p>
        <br />
      </p>

      <p>Обнародовать свои планы разработки принято далеко не всегда, но мы сознательно идем на этот шаг, чтобы на деле демонстрировать наши принципы по отношению к пользователям. И прежде всего это - быть максимально честными и открытыми по отношению к клиенту&#33; Так что же ждет наших подписчиков до конца 2011 года:</p>

      <br />
    <center><img alt="план развития" src="/project/type.gif" width="618" height="570" /></center>
      <br />

      <p>Мы указали здесь только основные планы нашего развития. За время реализации данной функциональности будет происходить много интересного. Вы можете стать полноправным участником разработки и воочию каждый день убеждаться в приближении к той конфигурации, которую Вы приобрели по льготной подписке. Версии СОП планируются к выходу каждый месяц. Уже сегодня Вы можете посмотреть, как будет выглядеть тот или иной функциональный модуль планируемый к разработке. Так, например, будет выглядеть Ваш календарь событий...</p>

      <br />
    <center><img alt="Социальный образовательный портал" src="/project/screen_3.jpg" width="628" height="397" /></center>
      <br />

      <p>Ваши обновления могут быть документально зафиксированы при оформлении подписки на текущую версию социального образовательного портала (СОП). Спешите оформить подписку сегодня и получить обширные возможности электронного обучения уже в конце текущего года&#33;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</asp:Content>
```

Address site: edusf.ru/project

All other browsers correctly display page. What can I do to IE?

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/) and if you have a problem with some HTML then *show us the HTML* and not some ASP that generates it.

Comment: `IE=EmulateFirefox` -- this will do nothing; it's not a setting that IE will recognise.

Answer (score 1):

The doctype must be the **first** thing in your page.

You have got the `<html>` element before it; this needs to be moved to after the doctype.

That will solve the problem for you.

Comment: changed place Doctype, but nothing has changed

Comment: Check your document mode using the IE developer tools window (press F12). Check your code validity by running the HTML through the W3C validator.